# Texture Baking creates Stripes

Tags: texture-baking

When I try to bake this texture, I am getting stripes on the image.
The object is just a plane with one side extruded then scaled on the z axis.

[image: baked image vs actual texture]
[image: node texture]

Link to the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: hi, we'd help you better if you show us your baking settings and your entire shader graph. I would be even better to also give your .blend file.

Comment: You could use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload the .blend file, because it's always easier to work with the file itself than trying to recreate something from pictures.

Comment: here is the blend file

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6010" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6010/)

Comment: Switch from GPU back to CPU render. GPU might not work as expected in Blender 2.80 Beta, because... well... it's still Beta.

Comment: @metaphor_set yah man, it works! I was skeptic at first but it works. haha. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the texture coordinates are very small, please check the UV space on your object. If it doesn´t have one, then you can also try switching from GPU to CPU render to bake.

Comment: yes, switching from GPU to CPU does the trick