# How to get rid of "black and white stripes" artifacts after baking a diffuse texture in Blender 2.9?

Tags: texture-baking

So, I'm working with a scanned model; already cleaned up, 4k faces, a lot of textures of 2048x2048. Because of the last thing I mentioned (many textures for one single and simple model), I want to bake those textures so I could get just one to work with (this is actually my first time doing baking). Everything seems to be set up correctly, but after I tried to do the baking process, some weird artifacts (black and white stripes) appeared covering the entire texture.

I tried to change the *Max Ray distance*, which didn't seem to work. I also checked faces orientation, and they were fine. Also, I changed the device to render from CPU to GPU, and nothing. Finally, I changed the image resolution of the texture and...well, it improved a little, somehow. I honestly don't know if there's a relation with the image resolution (didn't find anything about it on Blender documentation).

[image: Here's the textured model after changing the image resolution, it looks a bit better than the previous one I got]

Also, I followed [this answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149917/blender-2-8-bake-multiple-textures-into-one), since I've never worked with baking before, and I saw [this question too](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135003/texture-baking-creates-stripes), however, I did get the same result.

Comment: It looks like a UV map issue, maybe on the low poly. Have you checked it? Or make it again if you've changed some parts of the lowpoly geometry?

Comment: I used Smart UV Project for the UV Mapping, it looked way better than the original UVs, should I do something else for the UV mapping? like, manually?

Comment: It depends on the result you now have. Often, giving a little extrusion is needed.